# Revmob is used in gaming apps only?

Tags: ios, revmob

I am new to revmob. I have read about that i am confused that this ads service provider is only for games apps? I want to use in my app , my ap is not a gaming app so can i use revmob in my apps? Or revmob can e used in only gaming apps?

Comment: You'd better consult with creators of the Revmob. If you are seeking legal advice on licensing someone tools - SO is absolutely wrong place to ask.

Comment: No,you can use it in Application also and i am already using it.

Comment: @DeepGami  Thanks. can you please give link of ur app?

Answer (score 0):

Revmob can be used in any type of iOS app.

[Revmob iOS SDK](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html)

It may be useful for you to specify the nature of your app (if it appeals to a specific interest group maybe?) and get [targeted ads](http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html#profile) for your niche.